# How to close parent frame from JInternalFrame in java?

Tags: java, swing, frames

I want to close the parent frame on the click of a button in `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: Find the patent window, using something like SwingUtilities#windowForComponent and call dispose on it ... Although (personally) that kind of breaks the user experience expectations, but that's just me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent frame as the `JInternalFrame` the button is in or the `JFrame` or window it is contained in?
Use either:

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(button).dispose()
```

or

```
SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JInternalFrame.class, button).dispose();
```

or similar.

Javadoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html

Comment: Slightly shorter is calling [getTopLevelAncestor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getTopLevelAncestor--) on the JInternalFrame, and casting it to a Window.